# A disproof of RH?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Does this paper of Sondow et. al, in which they propose a disproof of RH, have reasonable arguments ?
[The Riemann Hypothesis is not true](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.08313#:%7E:text=Abstract%3A%20We%20show%20that%20there,universality%20of%20the%20zeta%20function.)

Comment: There seems to be a mathematician J. Sondow who worked in number theory that died in 2020, it is not clear if the arxiv paper is attributed to the same person: https://jonathansondow.github.io/

Comment: Since its (reported) first author died more than a year before the publication of the paper,  my bet would be "no".

Comment: @Michael The paper indeed cites J. Sondow as its first authors, and even links the specific website you linked.

Comment: @5xum : I see you are correct.  So the paper is attributed to that person...Perhaps he faked his own death.

Comment: @Michael It is not unheard of for posthumous publications - it's not like you scrap a paper if a co-author dies! (Although some acknowledgement of this fact would be expected, I guess.)

Comment: I did not know that he died. I know that in one of Broughan's books "The Equivalents of RH" there was an equivalence called "Sondow-Dumitrescu criterion" which appears as the names of two of three authors of the paper. That's why i take that paper seriously, but i am not sure about the validity of their argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On page 10 (paragraph disproof of the RH) they say that $\Re(\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s))>0$ for $\Re(s) \in (1/2,1)$ and $\Im(s)$ large, under the RH.

It is not true and this independently of the RH.

They messed with the $O(\log T)$ oscillation of $N(T)-\frac{T}{2\pi}\log(\frac{T}{2\pi})+\frac{T}{2\pi} $ at eq.26 as it is obviously not true that $\lim_{T\to \infty}f\ast g(T)\to 0$ for $f(u)=1_{u>2\pi}\log u, g(u)=\frac{u}{(\sigma-1/2)^2 + u^2)^2} $.

---

There is a proof that if $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros for $\Re(s)>\sigma$ then for any $c\in (\sigma,1)$, $\Re(\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s))$ changes of sign infinitely often on the line $\Re(s)=c$.

For $\Re(z)>0$ let $$F(z)=\int_c^{c+i\infty} (\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}+\frac{e^{i(s-1)}}{s-1}) e^{iz(s-c)}ds$$
It is standard that this thing converges absolutely under the $c>\sigma$ restriction.

By the Cauchy integral theorem $$F(z)=\int_c^2 
(\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}+\frac{e^{i(s-1)}}{s-1}) e^{iz(s-c)}ds+\int_2^{2+i\infty}\frac{e^{i(s-1)}}{s-1} e^{iz(s-c)}ds+\int_2^{2+i\infty} \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}e^{iz(s-c)}ds$$
$$ = G(z)-\int_2^{2+i\infty}\sum_{n\ge  2}  \Lambda(n)n^{-s} e^{iz(s-c)}ds=G(z)-e^{-izc}\sum_{n\ge  2} \frac{\Lambda(n) n^{-2}}{iz-\log n}$$
where

- $G(z)=\int_c^2 
  (\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}+\frac{e^{i(s-1)}}{s-1}) e^{iz(s-c)}ds+\int_2^{2+i\infty}\frac{e^{i(s-1)}}{s-1} e^{iz(s-c)}ds$ is analytic for $\Re(z)>-1$
- and $e^{-izc}\sum_{n\ge  2} \frac{\Lambda(n) n^{-2}}{iz-\log n}$ is analytic away from simple poles at the $-i\log n$

For $r >0$ let $$f(r)=\int_0^\infty \Re(\frac{\zeta'(c+it)}{\zeta(c+it)}) e^{-r t}dt=\Im(F(r))-\Im(\int_c^{c+i\infty} \frac{e^{i(s-1)}}{s-1} e^{iz(s-c)}ds)$$
If $\Re(\frac{\zeta'(c+it)}{\zeta(c+it)})$ didn't change of sign infinitely often then $\int_0^\infty \Re(\frac{\zeta'(c+it)}{\zeta(c+it)}) e^{-r t}dt$ would have a singularity at its abscissa of convergence, which is absurd as (the analytic continuation of) $f(r)$ is analytic for $r > -1$.

Comment: You mean that argument is invalid or that it can be proved that the real part of $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$ becomes negative for arbitrarily large imaginary parts of $s$ in the critical strip right of the critical line?

Comment: See my edit @მამუკაჯიბლაძე

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, looking at plots it seems that for very large (fixed) $\sigma$ the function $\Re\left(\frac{\zeta'(\sigma+it)}{\zeta(\sigma+it)}\right)$ oscillates around $0$ nearly periodically in $t$...

Comment: (which is hardly surprising as its Fourier modes are $k\log p$ with amplitudes $p^{-k\sigma}\log p$ for all primes $p$ and all natural $k$)

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback  @reuns  , I didn't know about this question until quite recently.  The error you mentioned in your answer has been corrected in the second version of our paper.   https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.08313   Your feedback will be greatly appreciated.